# Rails 4 asset not found

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4, asset-pipeline

In my application.rb `config.assets.enabled = false`

**My route:**

```
  get 'products/:category_id' => 'products#index', :as => 'products'
  get 'products/:category_id/:product_id' => 'products#show', :as => 'product'
```

When I go to the first route, assets are found in the proper location in public folder.
But in the second route `products/:category_id/:product_id'` is prepended in asset route and no route matches.
**eg:**

```
products/:category_id/:product_id/img/arrow-down.gif
```

but `localhost:3000/img/arrow-down.gif` finds the asset.

Please put me in the right path. I have been searching for the reason for hours.

```
addpointer:function(target, imgclass, imginfo, BeforeorAfter){
    var pointer=document.createElement("img")
    pointer.src=imginfo[0] **this line gives error
    pointer.style.width=imginfo[1]+"px"
    pointer.style.height=imginfo[2]+"px"
    if(imgclass=="rightarrowpointer"){
        pointer.style.left=target.offsetWidth-imginfo[2]-2+"px"
    }
    pointer.className=imgclass
    var target_firstEl=target.childNodes[target.firstChild.nodeType!=1? 1 : 0] //see if the first child element within A is a SPAN (found in sliding doors technique)
    if (target_firstEl && target_firstEl.tagName=="SPAN"){
        target=target_firstEl //arrow should be added inside this SPAN instead if found
    }
    if (BeforeorAfter=="before")
        target.insertBefore(pointer, target.firstChild)
    else
        target.appendChild(pointer)
}
```

note: its a js library, ddlevelsmenu

Comment: check the view scripts for the second route

Comment: Can you post some code from the view where you are accessing the asset. For example, the part containing image_tag.

Comment: the image is called from javascript, which is also located in public/js, commented from phone. will paste js soon. thanks a lot for quick reply.

Comment: Got the solution,

downarrow: ["img/arrow-down.gif", 11,7], //[path_to_down_arrow, arrowwidth, 
rightarrow: ["img/arrow-right.gif", 12,12], //[path_to_right_arrow, arrowwidth
changed those two lines to,

downarrow: ["/img/arrow-down.gif", 11,7], //[path_to_down_arrow, arrowwidth, rightarrow: ["/img/arrow-right.gif", 12,12], //[path_to_right_arrow, arrowwidth

Thanks, @emaillenin for pointing me to the js file.